# JSON Formatter (each object in new row)

Tags: json, mongodb

I am trying to import some test data to mongodb using mongo atlas, but only way to import multiple objects into database is by having each document (object) in seperate line. Are there any online tools to help me with that kind of formatting or should I make my own script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -c command-line option of [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) will do what you want.  For example, if your JSON documents are all in a file named in.json, you would simply run something like:

```
jq -c . in.json > out.json
```

jq can be used online, e.g. at https://jqplay.org/, where you would specify `.` as the filter and check the "Compact Output" box.

Another online option is https://tio.run/#jq

However, these online options may not be so useful with a large number of JSON documents, or with large JSON documents.